# Default AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Does anyone know of a way (or if it's even possible) to set the default preview AVD in Android Studio v0.4.5. Every time I create a new activity it shows it in a Nexus 4 preview but as I have TEGRA Note 7 and have a custom AVD created for that, I want to see that as the default.

Is this possible and, if so, can anyone advise how to do it? I've checked all the settings but can't see anything that jumps out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

In Android Studio 1.2.2, I was able to solve this problem by going to **Run > Edit configurations...**

From there, you can change the default emulator (avd) by clicking **Defaults**, then **Android Application**. From there, under **Target Device**, select your **Preferred Android Virtual Device** then click Apply or OK.

If that still does not work, you may need to also change this setting at the application level. Instead of clicking Defaults, click Android Application and select the name of the project in question. Then proceed to define the project-specific, preferred AVD as described above.