# What are the default AVD settings for android studio avd?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I changed the avd settings and now I can't come back to the default settings. I've tried many settings but either the avd becomes very big or very small.

These are my AVD settings now 
[image]

And this is my AVD

[image]

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906440/default-avd-in-android-studio) question too but does not answer my question.

Comment: I just see a black screen in your second image

Comment: it is just a black screen :)

Comment: Yes black screen with button on top right. Actually Avd was starting when I took this screen shot. The point to show  this is the size.

Comment: @BilalRafique we cannot determine the size from just the window screenshot. Show the size with full desktop screenshot so that the relative size can be seen. Also mention how you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Why go through the pain of figuring out what all you changed and reverting it? Just delete and create a new AVD with the API Level and screen dimension you had on the old AVD.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to do but I don't remember what dimensions and scale I had on my old AVD.

Comment: you have to select `Nexus 4' as seen in your screenshot. Dimensions for Nexus 4 are same. every time you select. The exact dimensions are also seen on the screenshot just next to the device name - Nexus 4 ... it is 768*1280 xhdpi

Comment: worse case scenario: just select a few different devices and start using whichever comes close to what you had earlier.

Comment: I've selected Nexus 4, now when I run it, it gives an error HAXM not installed. What is it?

Comment: refer this answer for how to resolve the HAXM error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30129536/1957401...